# Is the stepper motor DC or AC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, brushless-dc-motor, terminology

Is the stepper motor DC or AC  motor ?[image: uncropped photo of monitor showing a stepper motor for sale]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design. And a picture of a parts unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Comment: @BrianCarlton I don't see that you say.

Comment: @BrianCarlton  - Wouldn't this be a question about terminology?

Comment: It is not , because the explanation illustrates how it works and that is helpful for some

Comment: I wonder how a stepper will know how many steps you want it to make when you supply DC to it.

Comment: You have **DC motors** where you apply a DC voltage (e.g. battery) to its terminals and it runs. Then you have **brushless DC motors**, that even though they are called DC they have a driver/ controller that converts the supply DC voltage to an AC voltage (three phases). Similarly to the brushless DC motor, the **stepper motor** is also supplied DC voltage, however it converts it to AC voltage too (e.g. two phases). So just consider them as DC motors, since you supply a DC voltage to all, but bear in mind that the last two work with AC after conversion. See videos on how each works.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bipolar stepper.

It's not really AC, and it's not really DC. During steady state it's DC, but you need a pair of H bridges to drive it, which means you are switching polarities on the coils to make it move. That is kind of like AC.

So is it AC or DC? Yes, it is.